# Stuck with the same values when looping through database rows

Tags: php, loops, mysqli

I am trying to make a function where the following should happen:

1. Retrieve the ID value of all users in database.
2. Retrieve all numbers belonging to each user from an other table in the same database.
3. Add all the numbers belonging to each user together.

By using my code (see below), step 1 and 3 is working. At step 2, it is looping the correct amount of times but in every loop it retrieves the numbers belonging to the first ID from step 1.

Example:
Step 1 finds the following IDs: 1, 2, 3 and 4.
Step 2 loops 4 times, but retrieves the numbers belonging to ID 1 every time instead of retrieving the numbers to ID 1 in the first loop, ID 2 in the second etc.

My PHP:

```
$users_get = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id FROM users");
$users_num = mysqli_num_rows($users_get);
$users_list = array();
while($users_row = mysqli_fetch_array($users_get)){
    $users_list[] = $users_row;
}
foreach($users_list as $users_row){
    $users_items[] = array(
        'id' => $users_row['id']
    );
}

for($loop1 = 0; $loop1 < $users_num; $loop1++){
    $numbers_get = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT number FROM users_numbers WHERE userid = '".$users_items[$loop1]['id']."'");
    $numbers_num = mysqli_num_rows($numbers_get);
    $numbers_list = array();
    while($numbers_row = mysqli_fetch_array($numbers_get)){
        $numbers_list[] = $numbers_row;
    }
    foreach($numbers_list as $numbers_row){
        $numbers_items[] = array(
            'number' => $numbers_row['number']
        );
    }

    $numbers_added = 0;

    for($loop2 = 0; $loop2 < $numbers_num; $loop2++){
        $numbers_added = $numbers_added + $numbers_items[$loop2]['number'];
    }
}
```

I later added som echos to display the IDs and numbers that is retrieved and got the following result:

```
User ID: 1
Amount of numbers: 4
Numbers:
    4 (Belonging to ID 1)
    7 (Belonging to ID 1)
    5 (Belonging to ID 1)
    2 (Belonging to ID 1)
Total: 18

User ID: 2
Amount of numbers: 0

User ID: 3
Amount of numbers: 3
Numbers:
    4 (Belonging to ID 1)
    7 (Belonging to ID 1)
    5 (Belonging to ID 1)
Total: 16
```

The amount of numbers for ID 3 is correct, however the 3 retrieved numbers belongs to ID 1.

Another observation I made was if I edit the SELECT query inside loop 1:

```
"SELECT number FROM users_numbers WHERE userid = '".$users_items[$loop1]['id']."'"
```

And manually selects an ID, example:

```
"SELECT number FROM users_numbers WHERE userid = '3'"
```

Then it retrieves the correct numbers belonging to ID 3.

After hours of trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong I still haven't found anything, so any help is really appreciated! Is there something I can do with my current code to fix it, or maybe there is some other ways to achieve the desired function?

Comment: Why don't you just do a join between both tables? `SELECT id, number FROM users JOIN users_numbers ON users.id = users_numbers.userid`. It looks like this is what you are looking for. Then loop once over this and get your object together.

Comment: You really should try and understand what is returned from a query. Your Foreach loops after each While loop is totally unnecessary and is basically taking the array you want and making another exactly similiar array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments on my question, I ended up with the following code:

```
$users_get = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT a.id, SUM(b.number) AS number FROM users AS a INNER JOIN users_numbers AS b ON a.id = b.userid GROUP BY a.id ASC");
$loop1 = 0;

while($users_items[] = mysqli_fetch_array($users_get){
    echo "ID: ".$users_items[$loop1]['id']." - Num total: ".$users_items[$loop1]['number']."<br />";
    $loop1++;
}
```

The echo inside the while is only for testing purposes. When I run this, it displays a nice list with all the user IDs and the sum of each users numbers.

Comment: Again, as @RiggsFolly mentioned, you should really try to understand what's happening here, even if this works. You have 4 loops here, and a while and a for loop inside a for loop which could be a bottleneck in the future (i.e. your users_numbers table becomes huge, then for each users_num you loop for every number for the user, then you loop again.

Comment: @HanletEscaño I see that the for loops are unnecessary and removed them. I have also tried to play around with join, as you mentioned in your comment on my question. I managed to find an other way to achieve the desired function with less code by using join. I have updated the answer. Would that be an acceptable way of doing it?

Comment: Oh yes! That looks so much better than your initial code. Nice job!